# No visible @interface for 'NSArray<NSString *>' declares the selector 'addObject:' Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm shifting code from objc to swift, and I'm getting the error in -

```
[self.abc.requiredMetadataFields addObject:[NSUtils trimSpaces:currentElementValue]];
```

where the error says - `No visible @interface for 'NSArray<NSString *>' declares the selector 'addObject:'`

Now the above code is in `objc` whereas the class which I'm trying to use is in `Swift`, so the declaration in swift class is -

```
@objc public var requiredMetadataFields: [String] = []
```

I'm using var to make it `mutable` because the mutable array has the method `addObject` but I don't know what is causing the error and how I can fix it. Please help and let me know if any other information is needed.

Other variables are working fine so there's might not be the issue with joining `swift` with `objc`.

Comment: @Willeke actually not the accepted answer but the second answer helped.